mvn -B release:perform Unable to checkout from SCM
I am using Maven 3.9 and a Java Spring Boot 3.1.1 application with Bitbucket and Git.
I am trying to handle release versioning.
pom.xml
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git://ssh@bitbucket.org/travellinckcorpdevelopers/notification-service.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@bitbucket.org/travellinckcorpdevelopers/notification-service.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://bitbucket.org/travellinckcorpdevelopers/notification-service</url>
</scm>

The following command works as expected, it increments the project.version in the pom.xml file:
mvn -B release:prepare

Next, when I run this command in order to commit the updated pom to git:
mvn -B release:perform

It returns the following error:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.1.1:perform (default-cli) on project notification-service: Unable to checkout from SCM
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-clone command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] Cloning into 'checkout'...
[ERROR] ssh: Could not resolve hostname bitbucket.org:travellinckcorpdevelopers: Name or service not known
[ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please make sure you have the correct access rights
[ERROR] and the repository exists.

More info
To test that I do have access to the repository, I run:
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org

Which returns:
authenticated via ssh key.

Question
Is my connection defined incorrectly? Is my user (pub key) missing access rights? Do you know how I can fix this?

<connection>scm:git:git: — typo?

Hi @Sam, this might be incorrect, I copied it from other sources. I have tried a number of different connection urls. e.g. the following gets the same error:  scm:git:ssh://git@bitbucket.org/travellinckcorpdevelopers/notification-service.git

The following fixed it for me:
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@bitbucket.org/travellinckcorpdevelopers/notification-service.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@bitbucket.org/travellinckcorpdevelopers/notification-service.git</developerConnection>
    <url>ssh://git@bitbucket.org/travellinckcorpdevelopers/notification-service</url>
    <tag>notification-service-0.0.1</tag>
</scm>

So instead of https it is using ssh
I also had to delete the chached release.properties to get the new urls
